# Find start date based upon End Date and Duration - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a table in SQL Server which have following attributes.

```
ProjectID ||  Start_Date  ||   End Date    || Duration(Days)
1                             10-Jan-2013      5
2                             02-FEB 2013      16   
3                             26-Mar-2013      50  
.                                 .             .
```

I want to find start dates based upon the qualified days (Monday-Friday). For example for End Date: 10 January start date will be 04 January as 5 and 6 January are Saturday and Sunday.

I want to know how this could be possible in T-SQL (Function,Custom T-SQL Block). Any guidance and help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why did 04 January not qualify? It's Friday, and according to your list, it should work. Based on your input and expected output, it looks like you want End Date minus 5 business days, where business day is any of Mon-Fri. Please clarify which of the two you want.

Comment: @Neolisk 04 January will qualify. Sorry for that. If duration is greater than 5 days how can I find start date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
WITH tblProjects2 AS (
SELECT ProjectId, DATEADD(DAY, -Duration, EndDate) AS StartDate FROM tblProjects
)
SELECT ProjectId,
  CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(day, -2, StartDate)
       WHEN DATENAME(DW, StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(day, -1, StartDate)
       ELSE StartDate END AS ProperStartDate
  FROM tblProjects2
```

The approach is rather simple - when your new date falls on a weekend, subtract 1 or 2 days, depending on whether it's Saturday or Sunday respectively.

Test case structure for `tblProjects`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProjects](
  [ProjectId] [int] NULL,
  [StartDate] [date] NULL,
  [EndDate] [date] NULL,
  [Duration] [int] NULL
)
```

Test case data for same:

```
INSERT INTO tblProjects VALUES (1, NULL, '10-Jan-2013', 5);
INSERT INTO tblProjects VALUES (2, NULL, '02-FEB-2013', 16);
INSERT INTO tblProjects VALUES (3, NULL, '26-Mar-2013', 50);
```

**EDIT** - Same functionality, using a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getStartDate(@EndDate Date, @Duration int)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @newDate DATE;
   SET @newDate = DATEADD(day, -@Duration, @EndDate);

   RETURN (CASE 
         WHEN DATENAME(DW, @newDate) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(day, -2, @newDate)
         WHEN DATENAME(DW, @newDate) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(day, -1, @newDate)
         ELSE @newDate END)
END;
```

Then you can rewrite the above query like this:

```
SELECT ProjectId, dbo.getStartDate(EndDate, Duration) AS StartDate
  FROM tblProjects
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it's working perfect. Can you write this as a T-SQL function so that I could input End_Date and Working Day and get StartDate as output.

Comment: @wali: You're welcome. Please provide sample usage of the T-SQL function you want to have. It's not quite clear to me how you plan to specify Working Day. Also what about duration? If I were you, I would wrap Sunday and Saturday handling part into a function, and leave everything else out of it. So the input would be a single parameter of type DATE, output is the DATE shifted backwards by 1-2 days as required to represent a business day. You can then have a single SELECT in the above example.

Comment: I used the following query to update my table.

`WITH tblProjects2 AS (
SELECT ProjectId, DATEADD(DAY, -Duration, EndDate) AS StartDate FROM tblProjects
)
Update orig_project_table set start_date = (select
  CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(day, -2, StartDate)
       WHEN DATENAME(DW, StartDate) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(day, -1, StartDate)
       ELSE StartDate END AS ProperStartDate
  FROM tblProjects2 where tblProjects2.ProjectID = orig_project_table.ProjectID);`

Comment: If you can then please write a function performing the above query's functionality and having the following signature.

`Return Date getStartDate(@EndDate Date, @Duration int){}`

Answer (score 1):

A bit harder to read, but slightly faster

```
SELECT ProjectId, 
DATEADD(d, -Duration - CASE DATEDIFF(d, +Duration, EndDate) % 7 
  WHEN 5 THEN 1 
  WHEN 6 THEN 2 
  ELSE 0 END
  , EndDate)
FROM tblProjects
```